# How to generate random numbers in my situation

Tags: java

I generate randomly this expression `[0-9*]`. The symbol `'*'` is end line symbol. When it is generated, I jump to next line and fill it until `'*'` is generated again and so on. But in some cases, my first generated symbol is `'*'` and then jump to next line. for example:

```
116165464* 
56465*
* 
654*
64*
* 
14* 
and so on
...
..
.
```

As you can see, end line symbol like in 3 line is not suitable and useful. So I want to avoid this. How can I generate numbers and prevent to generate like 3 line and 6 line in my example? In other words, I want to generate lines which must to contain numbers ( there cannot be like 3 and 6 lines showed in my example)

*(Assume that I will delete all '*' symbols in the future, and if there will be lines like 3 and 6 in my example, there will be only empty space.)*

### My code looks like this: (it will generate symbols, c - char type)

```
for(int i = 1;i<max;i++){
if(i == max-1)
    c = '*';
c = numbers.charAt(rnd.nextInt(numbers.length()));
listChar.add(c);
```

Thanks

Comment: Well what does your code look like at the moment? There are various different ways of approaching this. For example, you could remember that the last thing you generated was a `*` and just generate 0-9 for the next iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my problem by doing this:

I add additional `char temp;`
I stored my previous symbol in `my temp`;
And check this condition:

```
temp = c;
c = generate symbol;
...
if(temp == c)
  continue;
if not equal
add(c)
```

*(It is kind of pseudo to get an idea)*

One from my results:

```
123355666778999
98631
112339
7
8
88877431
169
99988765544443211
112444456788999
981
1345
98876655543211
334667899
85431
34569
876521
1112334556678
88764333211
```

Comment: won't that also rule out that the same digit is generated twice in a row.

Comment: The numbers does not matter in this situation. It can be anything and it does not change the purpose. The thing is to avoid useless lines showed in my example in post.

Answer (score 0):

With small change to your code what you wanted may be achieved. 
I'm assuming that number = "0123456789*" based on your logic. If you want to achieve a non zero

```
// Next line will generate one number from 0 to 9 as we are ignoring last character.
listChar.add(numbers.charAt(rnd.nextInt(numbers.length()-1)));
for(int i = 2;i<max;i++){
    c = numbers.charAt(rnd.nextInt(numbers.length()));
    listChar.add(c);
    if(c == '*')
        break;
}
System.out.println(listChar);
```

Below code will ensure you can avoid adding an asterisk.

```
// Next line will generate one number from 0 to 9 as we are ignoring last character.
listChar.add(numbers.charAt(rnd.nextInt(numbers.length()-1)));
for(int i = 2;i<max;i++){
    c = numbers.charAt(rnd.nextInt(numbers.length()));

    if(c == '*')
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        listChar.add(c);
    }
}
System.out.println(listChar);
```

However there can always be a better algorithm to generate what you wanted. But this will work.

Comment: Yes it will work. but If I generate my number and if in some cases I will generate asterisk so my loop will be breaked (stopped). So this should not suitable situation. 'continue' statement should fit and do not stop loop.

Comment: Obviously I haven't written complete code as I do not want to doubt your intelligence. This code generates only one line of code. You will have to keep this in another loop to generate multiple lines. If you really want to put continue, you don't have to to keep continue in this case. Both keeping continue and not placing continue will give same result. Breaking when we generate * will ensure that you don't generate same length numbers for all lines. What ever works is well and good.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void genLine(){
    int random = Math.random()*10;
    System.out.print(random);
    while (random!=10)
        random = Math.random()*11;
        if (random == 10) System.out.print('*');
        else System.out.print(random);
    }
}
```

This will generate one line for you. The first character is a special case because it cannot be a '*' so I just hard coded it. In every other case generate a random number with one more possibility. If that extra possibility is chosen, print '*'.

Comment: Tip: Use \` and * won't be considered special.

Comment: while(random*=11) what is suppose to mean? It is not a valid expression, it should be boolean.

Comment: Sorry, type should be != fixed it

Comment: Ok i get it, but the problem that it contains '10' every time i created it. it is not flexible.